# Angular generate table with iterable part with rowspan attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

I would like to make a table with some repeatable part.

What I'm trying to achieve is to iterate over some data, in each part there is a four exact items.
below this is a basic view - which covers one object (heat)
[image]

**what I'm trying to achieve**
is to merge cells like on the picture below
however when I use rowspsan attribute the table is strange...

[image]

**working example on stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterable-table-rowspan-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let data of dataExample">
            <tr *ngFor="let element of data.data;  let i = index">
                <td *ngIf="i%2 === 0" rowspan=2></td>
                <td>{{element.track}}</td>
                <td>{{element.number}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td *ngIf="i%2 === 0" rowspan=2></td>
                <td *ngIf="i%2 === 0" rowspan=2></td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

*ngFor prevents creating excessive cells. You need one each pair of rows.